# Creating another column in R

Tags: r

This is my current data set
[image]

I want to take the numbers after "narrow" (e.g. 20) and make another vector. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not post data as images -- this is not easily reproducible.

Comment: You could try something along the lines of strsplit(data[,1],","). You'll have better luck getting an answer with reproducible data.

Comment: when working with data.table-format: `data.table::tstrsplit( Stimulus, ",")` will do the trick

Comment: readr ::parse_number(data$Stimulus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the substring "Narrow", followed by a `,` and zero or more spaces (`\\s+`), replace with blank (`""`) and convert to `numeric`

```
df1$New <- as.numeric(sub("Narrow,\\s*", "", df1$Stimulus))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `separate` to separate the `stimulus` column into two vectors.

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate(col = stimulus, 
           sep = ", ",
           into = c("Text","Number"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below, using `regmatches`

```
df$new <- with(df, as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(stimulus,gregexpr("\\d+",stimulus)))))
```

Answer (score -1):

You want [separate](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) from the tidyr package.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "a.b", "a.d", "b.c"))
df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"))
#>      A    B
#> 1 <NA> <NA>
#> 2    a    b
#> 3    a    d
#> 4    b    c
```